# The requested operation is invalid. Server Response: A value must be provided for item. clientRequestID:

Tags: powerapps

I've seen a lot of other posts like this, so I guess this is a common problem, but, I'm unable to fix it!

All I want is a multi-screen app that collects data from a bunch of fields and fills in an Excel table, nothing more than a basic form.

This is what I have:

[image]

The error I get when clicking the button is:

> "The requested operation is invalid. Server Response: A value must be
>   provided for item. clientRequestID: ..."

But what is wrong with this button?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Likely you have a field that is required which you are not providing a value for.

**Example:**

- With Sharepoint lists, the `Title` column is required by default
- When submitting a form without this column, a similar error is shown

**Some ideas:**

- Make all form fields visible within the PowerApp
- Check their `Required` property
- Set `Required` properties to `false` accordingly and try submitting again
- If that doesn't work, try `Patch`, `Defaults` rather than `SubmitForm()` to enter a new record into the Excel spreadsheet.

  - You get granular control over fields with `Patch`